# Knockout JS mouseover event being called on pageload

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a mouseover event attached to a bunch of inputs through knockout. Since the input is in a ko foreach block, a lot of these are being created and on page load, the mouseover event is being called for every single input that is added on the page. This is making my page load pretty slowly. Any idea why the event is being called on page load?

```
<!-- ko foreach: FilteredForecasts -->
     <td>
          <input class="tiny" type="number" min="0" max="80" data-bind="disable: Elapsed() || (!$parent.ResourceId() || $parent.EditingName()), value: Hours, css: { 'pending': Pending, 'saved': !Pending() && Hours() && !Elapsed(), 'highlighted': Highlighted, 'elapsed': Elapsed }, attr: { id: 'h_' + $index(), title: (!$parent.ResourceId() || $parent.EditingName() ? 'You must first save a resource to enter hours.' : TotalHoursString()) }, event: { mouseover: UpdateTotalHours($parent.ResourceId()) }" />
     </td>
<!-- /ko -->
```

and

```
self.UpdateTotalHours = function (resourceId) {
    if ((resourceId != null && resourceId != undefined) && self.Week() && self.Year() && (self.TotalHours() === null || self.TotalHours() === undefined)) {
        alert('here');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf8',
            url: staffingUtilities.baseUrl + 'Forecasting/GetResourceTotalUsage/',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                id: resourceId,
                year: self.Year(),
                week: self.Week()
            }),
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == 0) {
                    self.TotalHours(null);
                    return;
                }

                self.TotalHours(data);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your mouseover call in a function, the parens are causing UpdateTotalHours to be executed when your object is bound:

```
mouseover: function(){ UpdateTotalHours($parent.ResourceId()); }
```

See: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html